# Find count of records till specific row index in Mongodb using Spring data criteria Query with pagable

Tags: mongodb, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've 200 records in my mongodb I want to perform basic search operation along with auto suggestion functionality. When I type something in search text box then list of records should be displayed as a suggestion in the drop down. If I select the record from the suggestion list then I want to find the page Number of that particular record on which page that record is coming based on that I can fetch all the 50 records of that particular page and I can highlight the selected record in my data panel where I'm showing all the records.

I'm facing issue in writing query for finding page number of the selected record I'm passing the ID of selected record from the UI and based on that ID I want to find the page number of that record.

I've tried using count query but but I didn't find a way to count the number of records till the particular row index in Mongo, so based on that I can calculate the page number.

```
[
{
    "name": "ABC1",
    "id": "33d47e5da3a08555dceb17e34"
},
{
    "name": "ABC2",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e8f"
},
{
    "name": "ABC3",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e99"
},
{
    "name": "ABC4",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e77"
},
{
    "name": "ABC5",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e66"
},
{
    "name": "ABC6",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e55"
},
{
    "name": "ABC7",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e78"
},
{
    "name": "ABC8",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e68"
},
{
    "name": "ABC9",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e55"
}
```

]

I want to know the below record is available on which pageNumber. For that I need a Total record count till the ABC5 record.

```
{
    "name": "ABC5",
    "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e66"
}
```

**So that I can find the pageNumber like this;**

```
int pageNumber = count/pageLimit;

final int pageLimit = 3;
int pageNumber = count/pageLimit;
Page<T> page = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageLimit));
```

**And this should be my final Result:**

```
    [
    {
        "name": "ABC4",
        "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e77"
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC5",
        "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e66"
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC6",
        "id": "5f47e5da3a08555dceb17e55"
    },
]
```

Can someone please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm facing issue` can you clarify this? Can you show us what you already did?

Comment: I'm using Criteria query to fetch count of all the records till the specific row. Based on that I can calculate page number to fetch records of particular page using Pagable. But I'm not able to do that because we don't have auto increment functionality in the sorted order.